# Cannot delete linked list when calling the destructor

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor

```
void Set::remove(Set::Node* p) {
    if(p == nullptr) return;
    Node* tmp = p->next;
    delete p;
    return remove(tmp);
}

Set::~Set() {
    remove(list);
}

class Set {
public:
~Set();

private:
    struct Node {
        int value;
        Node* next;
    };
    Node* list;
}

Set& Set::operator= (const Set& other) {
    if(this == &other) return *this;
    list = copy(other.list);
    sizeOfList = other.sizeOfList;
    return *this;
}

Set::Node* Set::copy(Set::Node* list) {
    if(list == nullptr) return nullptr;
    return cons(list->value, copy(list->next));
}

Set::Node* Set::cons (int value, Set::Node* next) {
    Node* tmp = new Node;
    tmp->value = value;
    tmp->next = next;
    return tmp;
}

Set() : list(nullptr), sizeOfList(0) {};
```

I wanted to test the destructor, so I call it manually(on the last line of the program)

```
x.~Set();
```

but then I got *** error for object 0x100103ad0: pointer being freed was not allocated. I dont know what I have done wrong. I have read as many related posts as possible but cant find a solution. Hope someone's help!

Comment: Are you allocating memory somewhere?

Comment: Destructors are called automatically if you do things right. Never call them yourself. If you need to, believe me, you will know.

Comment: Are you saying my code is right but just not calling it manually?

Comment: Do set `Set::list` to `nullptr` in constructor, or it's uninitialized?

Comment: Yes, it used initialization lists to set list to nullptr

Comment: 1) Where is your main() program you say you ran?  2) You shouldn't be calling the destructor explicitly.  If you want to see a destructor in action, then let the Set variable go out of scope naturally. `int main() { { Set s; //... } }`  Note the inner set of braces.  That s variable will have the destructor automatically called when the scope leaves the inner set of braces.

Comment: It also would help more if you posted valid code that can be compiled.  That Set class has no closing semicolon, and the definition of Set::remove appears before the Set class.  If you have a runtime issue, it is imperative you post correct code.

Comment: Don't use recursion for this. Just write a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have no constructor that sets list from an undefined value to a known one, so `list` is never being set to anything and you are trying to delete it.

Try adding a default constructor that sets `list = nullptr;`

Comment: I did. Set() : list(nullptr), sizeOfList(0) {};

Comment: `Set` also needs a copy-constructor.